# Preventing an iframe from being loaded each time the parent page is viewed

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, axshockwaveflash

BACKGROUND:

I will be creating a website using a 3rd party CRM such as Concrete5.  On one of the pages, I wish to display content from another web server. The other web server is some proprietary industrial controller and utilizes x-shockwave-flash.  The industrial controller is legacy hardware, and I can't modify it.  When initially accessing this industrial controller, logon credentials must be entered.  The parent website will only be displayed on a single client, and will be always open.

PROBLEM:

When navigating between the parent website pages, the industrial controller web server asks for credentials each time the page is accessed.  This is not acceptable.

BEST SOLUTION:

Somehow figure out the cookies or what ever the x-shockwave-flash based industrial web server requires.  I know nothing about flash, and don't know where to start.  I also expect I will never be able to provide you enough information to suggest a solution.  If you have ideas, great!  Otherwise I am going to abandon trying to do so.

HOPEFUL SOLUTION:

Keep the iframe open even when navigating to a page on the parent website which doesn't include the iframe.

FIRST ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:

I created super parent website which included an iframe to the parent website which included the iframe to the industrial controller and an iframe to the parent website for all the other pages.  I then used JavaScript to show/hide the appropriate iframe based on the viewed page.  While this worked on a very simple HTML page, I don't think I can incorporate the 3rd party CMS.

QUESTION:

Can JavaScript or some other technology on the parent website be used so that the iframe to the industrial web server is not re-loaded each time the the page on parent website which has this iframe is accessed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Fictional Concrete5 Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="?p=1">one</a> <a href="?p=2">two</a> <a href="?p=3">three</a></p>
        <?php
                $p=empty($_GET['p'])?1:intval($_GET['p']);
                switch($p) {
                        case 1:case 2:
                        echo('Page '.$p);
                        break;
                        case 3:
                        echo('Page 3<hr><iframe src="http://example.com/"></iframe>');
                        break;
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no. iframes are part of a page. if the page is reloaded, then the iframe is reloaded as well. you could use an old-school `<frameset>`, which does split your window into multipiple independent sections, but those open up all kinds of other problems... and would still cause all frames to reload if the parent frameset container is reloaded.

Comment: potentially use cookies to indicate the remote content has been retieved and DOMDocument to clone the contents and save locally - then check the cookie and serve local copy? just an idea

Comment: @MarcB  Forgot about the `<frameset>` tags.  Probably don't want to use, but thank you.

Comment: @RamRaider  Yes, maybe.  I will look into.